# Imaginary eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Consider the matrix

$$A(\mu) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1&  0 & 0 \\ -1 & -i\mu & 0 & i \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 &i & -1 & i\mu \end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix is for $\mu \in \mathbb R$ skew hermitian, i.e. all the eigenvalues are imaginary.

Let $(\mu_i)_i$ be a sequence of real numbers.

We consider the product

$$M=\prod_{i=1}^n A(\mu_i).$$

I claim the following two facts are true (observed numerically):

1.) If $n$ is odd, then all eigenvalues are imaginary (this is non-trivial for $n\ge 3$ since the matrix $M$ is in general not skew hermitian anymore)

2.) Show that the eigenvalues satisfy for $n \in 2\mathbb N_0+1$ that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ if and only if $-\lambda$ is. If you show this for one eigenvalue it will hold for all eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: Characteristic polynomial for odd $n$ is$$1+(3+\prod_{i=1}^n\mu_i^2)t^2+t^4$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Are you sure? I computed it for $n=3$ and got something completely different (the coefficient of $t^2$ is a messy polynomial in $\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3$)

Comment: Well unless Mathematica has a bug... :)

Comment: @AntoineLabelle OMG it seems I have a bug! I multiplied the matrices entrywise!!

Comment: Sorry my first comment is complete rubbish

Comment: Hahaha ok that explains it. Using sage I got, for $n=3$, $k_1^2k_2^2k_3^2+\sum_{sym} (k_1^2k_2^2 +2k_1^2k_2k_3+4k_1^2+4k_1k_2) +18$ for the coefficient of $t^2$

Comment: Another quite surprising property is that the characteristic polynomial is symmetric in the $\mu_i$, that is, the eigenvalues are independent of the order in which the multiplication is done. I wonder what explains that.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393758/imaginary-eigenvalues#comment1005308_393758), in so many other respects Mathematica often DWYM (for example, it's perfectly happy to do the multiplication `{{a, b}, {c, d}}.{x, y}` without requiring, as it technically should, that you transpose it `{x, y}.Transpose[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]`), but the decision to make the default way of multiplying matrices be entrywise is surely a wart.

Comment: the Mathematica command for matrix multiplication is `Dot` --- so to multiply a list of matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots A_n$ you could enter `Dot@@Table[A[i],{i,1,n}]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define the unitary and Hermitian matrices
$$U=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
 i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;
V=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
 i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\;\;U^2=I=V^2,$$
and note that, for $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$UA(\mu)U=\bar{A}(\mu),\;\;VA(\mu)V=-A(\mu).$$

$\bullet$ Hence if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\prod_{i=1}^n A(\mu_i)$, then
$$0=\overline{\det\bigl(\lambda I-\prod_i A(\mu_i)\bigr)}=\det\bigl(\bar{\lambda} I-\prod_i\bar{A}(\mu_i)\bigr)=\det\bigl(\bar{\lambda} I-\prod_i UA(\mu_i)U\bigr)=\det\bigl(\bar{\lambda} I-\prod_i A(\mu_i)\bigr)=0.$$
So the eigenvalues come in complex conjugate pairs: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\prod_i A(\mu_i)$, then also $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue. (This holds irrespective of whether $n$ is even or odd.)

$\bullet$ Similarly, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\prod_{i=1}^n A(\mu_i)$ and $n$ is an odd integer, then
$$0=\det\bigl(\lambda I-\prod_{i=1}^n VA(\mu_i)V\bigr)=\det\bigl(\lambda I-(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^n A(\mu_i)\bigr)=\det\bigl(\lambda I+\prod_{i=1}^n A(\mu_i)\bigr)=0,$$
so the eigenvalues come in inverse pairs for odd $n$: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then also $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. This proves property 2.

$\bullet$ Since $\det A(\mu)=1$ for any $\mu$, the product of the four eigenvalues of $\prod_{i=1}^n A(\mu_i)$ equals unity. This gives for odd $n$ the following three possibilities (with real $c$ and $\phi$):
**A.** $\lambda_1=ic$, $\lambda_2=-ic$, $\lambda_3=i/c$, $\lambda_4=-i/c$ (this is property 1),
**B.** $\lambda_1=c$, $\lambda_2=-c$, $\lambda_3=1/c$, $\lambda_4=-1/c$,
**C.** $\lambda_1=e^{i\phi}$, $\lambda_2=-e^{i\phi}$, $\lambda_3=e^{-i\phi}$, $\lambda_4=-e^{-i\phi}$.
The eigenvalues are either all four on the imaginary axis, or on the real axis, or on the unit circle.

Comment: I think you also need to exclude the case of four eigenvalues $\lambda, -\lambda, \frac{1}{\lambda},-\frac{1}{\lambda}$ all real.

Comment: indeed, thanks for pointing this out.